# setting State from render const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to setState, in my case, `feedbackLogId`, which is required to called a function that will GET the details of feedback according to the `feedbackLogId`. The const, however is gotten from the previous screen and I am only able to set the const in render() method.

### First Screen

Here, I fetch the data from a WebAPI and render it in a FlatList where there will be multiple feedbacks.

```
dataSource = [{
  "feedbackLogId": 1,
  "name": "Test1",
  "comment": "Hello",
}, {
  "feedbackLogId": 2,
  "name": "Test2",
  "type": "Hi",
}, {
  "feedbackLogId": 3,
  "name": "Test3",
  "type": "Morning",
}]
```

When I press on one of the Feedback, I would like to get navigated to the second screen, but save the value of feedackLogId, so that i can get more details about the feedback.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.listItem}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('FeedbackDetails', {value: item.feedbackLogId})}
      >
</TouchableOpacity>
```

### Second Screen

I have tried many methods, but it's either `props.navigation` being undefined or several other errors.

This is done in constructor(props)

```
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            dataSource: [],
            feedbackLogId: ''
       }
        this.getPendingDetails = getPendingDetails.bind(this)
    }
```

I would like to call the function getPendingDetails in componentDidMount() and this is where I need my feedbackLogId.

```
componentDidMount() {
        //this is where I would need the state of feedbackLogId
        this.getPendingDetails(this.state.feedbackLogId);
    }
```

Only inside render am I able get the value of the data passed from another screen

```
    const feedbackLogId = this.props.navigation.getParam('value', 'nothing')
```

I have tried to call `const feedbackLogId = this.props.navigation.getParam('value', 'nothing')` in other parts of the screen but am getting errors such as `this.props` being undefined. Is there a way to solve this problem? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getDerivedStateFromProps

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps = (props, state) => { 
    console.log('props',props.navigation)
    const feedbackLogId = props.navigation.getParam('value', 'nothing');
    if(feedbackLogId){
    this.getPendingDetails(feedbackLogId);
    }
  }
```

In your constructor

```
 this.getPendingDetails = getPendingDetails.bind(this)
```

to

```
 this.getPendingDetails = this.getPendingDetails.bind(this)
```

Comment: let me know if you are getting any problem

Comment: It says that this.getPendingDetails is not a function and this.getPendingDetails is undefined

Comment: ```TypeError: TypeError: this.getPendingDetails is not a function. (In 'this.getPendingDetails(feedbackLogId)', 'this.getPendingDetails' is undefined)```

Comment: use arrow functin

Comment: what do i use arrow function for?

Comment: are you getting console.log('props',props.navigation) ?

Comment: I can get the value of feedbackLogId, but not able to call ```this.getPendingDetails``` function. Making it arrow function didnt fix it

Comment: Im getting ```undefined is not a function (near '..._class.setState...')``` this error now

Comment: This is due my getPendingDetails fetches data from webapi and setStates of dataSource and isLoaded