# setState from render const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to setState from the const that I got from rendering. This is because I am passing the value from another sceen. I would like to set State as I need that value to perform fetch method.

**This is where I have the states, in constructor**

```
this.state = {
   feedbackLogId: ''
}
```

**This is inside my render.**

```
const feedbackId = this.props.navigation.getParam('value', 'nothing sent')
```

I would like to set the state of `feedbackLogId` to the value of `feedbackId`.

Comment: We need more information though. What do you have in `another screen`, is it a component? If it is, you can pass the feedbackId to the component as a prop, and use the prop for fetching

Comment: Please don't post the same question again: [React Native calling setState by getting const from render which is data passed from another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872493)

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice (in most cases) to set a prop to state, as you can just access the data you need from the prop. For instance, if the prop might change later, would you want the state to also change? If so, just use the prop. If you need the initial prop, but want to maintain the original in state, that would be a case to set it to state. More information is needed to properly answer this question.

Comment: Hey! since this was a repost, could you look at my first post to get more details. 
[setting state from render const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872493/setting-state-from-render-const/59872614?noredirect=1#comment105890583_59872614)

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this because setState triggers a re-render. If for some reason you don't want to use the prop directly and need to have it in state as well, you should look at the getDerivedStateFromProps life-cycle hook.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops